# how to transfer a file from a remote machine to my pc

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I was trying to transfer a file from a remote machine to my pc using sftp. However, it gives me the error message

```
Couldn't open local file "tx_timed_samples.cpp" for writing: Permission denied
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you don't have permissions to do it, as you can see in your posted code:

```
Couldn't open local file "tx_timed_samples.cpp" for writing: Permission denied
```

Comment: but i have changed the permission of that file using chmod already

Answer (score 0):

Check your current path permission.
Try to make any file in your current path before conneting to remote server.
If "tx_timed_samples.cpp" is already exist in your current path, check permission and check running status if it is excutable file.(it seems just text file, might not be excutable I think.)

Comment: I have tried that yesterday and it seems that I do not have the permission to create any file in the path. Thanks for the help